# Which image elements should get a retina version?

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display

I'm building a page which is supposed to be full retina ready. I'm creating a retina version of all the small-medium images.

It looks good when you look at the 100x100 pixel version of a 50x50 image on devices with high density screens. But what if the image is much larger? Like a background image of a slider with 1700x600 pixel dimensions, should this get a retina version as well? The image's size is already much bigger than almost every mobile device's resolution. Would a 1700x600 or a 3400x1200 image look different on a 640x960 display?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about retina enabled laptops, and iPads... In my experience most images you can save at a scale of about 150% the expected viewing size, and they still look great on a high density screen. You should play with compression quality as well, a lot of times you can lower the quality and still have an image that looks great because of the shear amount of extra pixels.

See this for an example of what I'm talking about: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/rwd_img_compression/